# Finding a power spectrum in Python, without using the inbuilt FFT function

Tags: python, python-3.x, physics

I would like to find the a power spectrum with Python using the following formula:

[Power spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bC5S.png)

I am trying to plot the array that should follow from this with this:

```
P = []
for k in range(0,int(N/2)):
    P.append((2/N)*(sum(x[k]*np.cos(2*np.pi*nu*t[k]))**2+(sum(x[k]*np.sin(2*np.pi*nu*t[k])))**2))
```

where nu are the frequencies:

```
nu = []
for j in range(0, int(N/2), 2):
nu.append(j/T)
```

x and t come from a dataset, and N is just the total of all x.

Python keeps telling me: 'Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'' 
What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure it's something to do with multiplying the wrong types of data with eachother. But I'm not sure how to change this.

I know there is an inbuild FFT function, but I think it would be really instructive for me to get this function to work.

Comment: Well what are the data types of everything you're multiplying together?

Comment: They are arrays (or lists?) but some have index k and some have index j, which decides what python should do with them. But I probably didn't code that correctly, did I? And then there is pi, which is a float, but that should just multiply easily with everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nu is a list, so the piece of code `2*np.pi*nu*t[k]` is giving you the error.Try something like:

```
for i in nu:
    P.append((2/N)*(sum(x*np.cos(2*np.pi*nu[i]*t))**2+(sum(x*np.sin(2*np.pi*nu[i]*t)))**2))
```

This way you are summing the quantity `(2/N)*(sum(x*np.cos(2*np.pi*nu[i]*t))**2+(sum(x*np.sin(2*np.pi*nu[i]*t)))**2)` for every i.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. But I'm not sure if I'm just summing over the terms with index k, which I should. Could you explain how to make sure what exactly it is I'm summing over?

Comment: You're right, actually the second for should be removed at all, sum takes an iterable argument.